# awk extract string and replace it from a line then print the new line

Tags: shell, awk, sed

I am trying to parse the Apache logs.
And I got some logs below,

```
10.10.112.17 - - [02/Jul/2015:16:42:10 -0400] "GET /test/1234 HTTP/1.1" 304 - "https://basrurl/test/12345" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:38.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/38.0"
```

I try to use awk to replace "/test/1234" and "/test/test_id" in this files.
How I can do it ?

Comment: Note the "1234"  is always changed.

Comment: When you say replace "/test/1234" _and_ "/test/test_id", do you mean _with_? What have you tried and where are you stuck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will replace /test/anynumberofdigits with /test/test_id

```
sed 's /test/[0-9]* /test/test_id g'
```

note that your log statement has test/1234 and test/12345, this will replace both.

Comment: It really works. Thanks. However, I wonder whether I can do it by "awk". I am learning "awk" command.

Comment: `awk '{gsub(/test\/[0-9]*/,"test/test_id",$0)}'` should do.